# Problems sending commands to USB programmer

Tags: vb.net, hid

I'm writing a program in VB.NET 2010 that will connect to the [PICkit(TM) 1 FLASH Starter Kit](http://www.microchip.com/pickit1/)'s USB programmer and send it commands to turn on or off something connected to the attached [eLab16m](http://www.elabtronics.com/products__cat_elab16m.htm) board, for example, an LED. This is all done by using the [libhid.net DLL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libhidnet/).

The vendor id is `&H4D8` and the product id is `&H32`.

**Update** I've written a console program that outputs what's happening. Here's the output:
[image: output from usb programmer test]
Where it says `device with report id 0x10`, I am trying to query the firmware version from the USB Programmer.

**Update 2** I've fixed the problem with the Wacom Bamboo tablet by uninstalling its software and drivers from my computer. The error has disappeared from the command line, but it still shows the `0x10` error.

Comment: Sounds to me like the 'bufferSize' is zero, and should not be.

Comment: @UpTheCreek Would you know any way of changing it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when I was using this code:

```
Dim response As Byte() = prog.WriteRead(&H10, {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8})
```

...it turned out that the `ReportID` parameter (`&H10` or `0x10` in the error message) was the wrong one. Probably because I copy/pasted from the example program included with libhid.net. :S

So basically the answer is that you need to find out the right ReportID for the device you're using.

Comment: @sil, not so much the Copy but the Paste is always kind of messy. ;)